# Ambiguity in relative minimum

Tags: algebra-precalculus

## 1 on picture below

I saw that aren't necessarily any locations at which the derivative changes signs from negative to positive, kmolhjnf a minimum, but I do know that f(0) is the point with the least value on the interval [0,5] by visual comparison of areas. What is the correct answer to this question? According to my teacher, the answer is (D) but that doesn't make sense to me.[image]

for my precalculus class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is 0 and 5 because near 0 the function is increasing, so locally 0 is the minimum, and the function is decreasing leading up to 5, so 5 must be smaller than the surrounding points.

The important thing to learn here is that local extreme need not have $f' = 0$. Local extrema are points which are lower/higher than all other points in a small neighborhood around them.